# How to custom checkbox in listview to check only one like radio button

Tags: android, checkbox, radio-button

I have list which contain checkbox in each list and I want to define these checkbox for only one of check box can select (like radio button) anybody have any ideas?

Comment: then why don't you use radio button instead of checkbox you can also customized the UI of control

Answer (score 0):

Set clickable/focusable/focusableInTouchMode to false, and then the list item vill receive the click, then set the checkbox state manually.
If the checkbox is clickable, then the item will not receive any event, this is an old Android bug still not fixed. Even worse if you want to use EditTexts, but don't get me there